# Как сделать так чтобы в одной сущности были другие

Tags: java

Есть 2 сущности Developer и Skill. Необходимо использовать MVC модель, DAO c CRUD операциями есть ControllerDev и ViewDev тоже. Сущности лежат в отдельных файлах. Не могу понять как мне реализовать Set skills. При создании Developer добавлять skill.

```
public class Developer {

    private Long id;
    private Set<Skill> skills;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<Skill> getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }
    public void setSkills(Set<Skill> skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }
```

---

```
public class Skill {

    private Long id;
    private String name;

   get и set
```

Comment: попробуйте переформулировать вопрос, сейчас непонятно в чем у вас проблема

Comment: Вопрос был такой, как мне создать сущность, которая в себе содержит другую сущность, и выводить на экран

Answer (score 0):

Необходимо проаннотировать классы сущностей соответствующими аннотациями @Entity.
Если используете Intellij IDEA - вам повезло, поскольку в ней есть генератор маппинга **entity <-> таблица БД**, который автоматически проставит все необходимые аннотации над полями и связи @OneToMany.

[image: IDEA mapping]